# Conference name and paper ref in beamer title slide

Tags: beamer

How can I add extra information on the title slide? in particular I'd like to put in the conference name and location as well as a reference to the paper work is based on.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the available fields to add extra information; the optional arguments can be used to prevent the extra information from appearing in footlines/headlines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title[The Title]{The Title}
\subtitle[The Subtitle]{The Subtitle \\ Based on A Really Important Paper \\ by Some Other Author}
\author[The Author]{The Author}
\institute{The Institute \\ Some Location}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]